# How one pass C compiler deal with labels?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Some times labels is used before declared, for example:

```
void test() {
  goto label;
  label: return;
}
```

when an one pass compiler parses the first statement, it doesn't know where the label is, until the `label:` statement comes.

Since one pass compiler only parses the code once, there's no way to leave the `label` alone and comes back later, right?

So what is the usual way to deal with this in an one compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Backpatch. Use the destination address field in the generated branch operation to create a linked list of unresolved uses of the label, putting the head of the list in the label symbol table. When the label is defined, walk the list, overwriting ("patching") each link with the correct value.
2. If you're allowed to generate symbolic assembly code, just output the label name and let the assembler deal with it.

Comment: So in case 1, even the compiler is an one pass compiler, it still do some kinds of drawbacks, right? And in case 2, does that mean I cannot produce error messages if the label is not defined?

Comment: @reavenisadesk: you need to backpatch to correctly handle if-then-else, front-tested loops and short-circuiting booleans, among other things. So it's a standard technique in one-pass compilers. If you can't backpatch (eg. you can't hold the compiled code in memory) then you need an extra pass.

Comment: As for the "let the assembler do it" option, you can let the assembler provide undefined label errors, too. Although nothing stops you from keeping a set of as-yet-undefined labels (or a map to line of first use) and removing labels from the set when you see the definition. Then you produce errors at the end for never-defined labels. (Undefined label errors always come at the end of scope, since you can't know earlier that the label won't be defined..)